# Finding and replacing a pattern with bold and normal characters

Tags: regex, text

So as the title suggests I have a crazy thing that I need to do and was wondering if there is a faster way to do it. Basically I have a list in Word format. On each line there is data that looks like this:

**Bold Text** Normal Text

I need to insert something between the bold and normal text. Is there any way to find only the places that match that pattern (i.e. **B** space here N)? I could then easily insert what I need. Maybe something with regex?

Comment: You mean within word, or via a web language? Did you try anything?

Comment: Within Word. Word has decent find/replace function, but can't mix different font styles as far as I can tell. Word also supports Regex in the find/replace but I have no experience using it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so a bit extreme idea:

The document you are talking about, is docx? if not, I guess you can convert it to it.

I've tried that on a docx file, without a regex, but i'm sure that you'll be able to take care of this :)

So!

- Extract the docx file as a zip archive

  - You can add .zip to the file name, as an extension, or just open with an archiver - such as 7zip.
- Navigate to the folder named `word`, under the extracted folder.
- Open `document.xml` with your preferred editor
- Every part of the text that changes his style - has a different tag
- Find some string that looks like that: `<w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000"><w:rPr><w:b w:val="1"/><w:rtl w:val="0"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">bold text </w:t></w:r>`

  - A string style section looks like that ^
  - The tag `<w:b w:val="1"/>` with the 1 value, indicates that this string inside ("bold text ") has the bold style.
- Create a string that looks like what I've shown above, and insert the text you like. If for example you want the new text to have another style, like italic, so use `<w:i w:val="1"/>` (with `i` instead of `b`).

My example:
I wanted to add pictures, but I don't have enough reputation :(
It looks like:

- Before: **bold text** normal text
- After: **bold text**  *hi im new* normal text

The XMLs example:
https://gist.github.com/arieljannai/08756ef562962eee0798

So, the only thing you need to do now, is build a regex that will find you the parts with `w:b` tags and all of the surrounding, and than you have it :)

Good luck!

**EDIT:** A regex example I made, that matches a style string line, like I put in the example above:
`(<w:r.*?>(?:<w:b\s{1}.*?\/>){1}.*?(?:<w:t\s{1}.*?>(.*?)<\/w:t>)<\/w:r>)`

- The regex matches a section, between the `<w:r>` tag (first group).
- The first non-matching group make sure it has the bold tag (`(?:<w:b\s{1}.*?\/>)`)
- The second non-matching group finds the tag that the text is with in it (the `<w:t>` tag).
- inside the second non-matching group, there's the second matching group `(.*?)` which actually holds the text of that style string. (second group).

**So you have the whole style string in the *first group*, and only the actual text in the *second group*.**